# C functions in finding a max value

Tags: c

How to write a C Function that takes three integers as arguments and returns the value of the largest one.

```
int largest(int x,int y,int z)
{
    int val1,val2,val3;
    int maximum;

     printf("enter value \n");
     scanf("%d",&val1,&val2,&val3);

     maximum=largest(val1,val2,val3);

      printf("the largest integer is %d = \n",maximum);
     return 0;
    }

int largest(int x,int y,int z)
{
    if(x>=y && x>=z)
         printf("Largest number = %d", x);
    if(y>=x && y>=z)
         printf("Largest number = %d", y);
    if(z>=x && z>=y)
         printf("Largest number = %d", z);                  
    }
```

I have tried this codes but they don't work i need help please I am also a beginner at this

Comment: `int largest(int x,int y,int z)` please give this function a return value, use `42` if not sure what to return.

Comment: The easiest is probably to use/create a function that takes two interger and returns the larger integer, then call that twice.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine.

```
     int val1,val2,val3;
     int maximum;

     printf("enter value \n");
     scanf("%d %d %d",&val1,&val2,&val3);

     maximum=largest(val1,val2,val3);

     printf("the largest integer is %d = \n",maximum);
     return 0;
    }

int largest(int x,int y,int z){
    int max;
    max=x;
    if(y>max){
        max=y;
    }
    if(z>max){
        max=z;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int largest(int x, int y, int z);
int main() {
    int val1, val2, val3;
    int maximum;
    printf("enter value \n");
    scanf("%d", &val1, &val2, &val3);
    maximum = largest(val1, val2, val3);

    printf("the largest integer is %d = \n", maximum);
    return 0;
}

int largest(int x, int y, int z){
    if (x >= y && x >= z)
        return x;
    if (y >= x && y >= z)
        return y;

    // otherwise
    return z;
}
```

The problem is that you wanted the method to return the largest value, but simply didnt do that - the code is not compiling because the largest function is defined to "return" an `int` but there's no return statement anywhere in your function.

If you dont know what exactly "returning function" is then take a look at this tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Comment: Could simplify: `if (y >= x && y >= z)` --> `if (y >= z)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty short way of doing what you want:

```
int largest(int a, int b, int c)
{
    a = (a > b) ? a : b;
    a = (a > c) ? a : c;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a value you must use a return statement in function.
Let us inspect what you've done,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int largest(int x,int y,int z)/* missed ';' */
/* missed 'void main()' */ 
{
 int val1,val2,val3;
 int maximum;

  printf("enter value \n");
  scanf("%d",&val1,&val2,&val3); /* missed format specifier for other two values */

  maximum=largest(val1,val2,val3);

  printf("the largest integer is %d = \n",maximum);
  return 0;
}

int largest(int x,int y,int z)
{
 if(x>=y && x>=z)
 printf("Largest number = %d", x);/* written print statement instead of return statement  */
 if(y>=x && y>=z)
 printf("Largest number = %d", y);/* written print statement instead of return statement  */
 if(z>=x && z>=y)
 printf("Largest number = %d", z);/* written print statement instead of return statement  */               
}
```

After modification the code should be like this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int largest(int x,int y,int z);
int main()
{
 int val1,val2,val3;
 int maximum;

 printf("enter value \n");
 scanf("%d %d %d",&val1,&val2,&val3);
 maximum=largest(val1,val2,val3);
 printf("the largest integer is %d  \n",maximum);
 return 0;
}

int largest(int x,int y,int z)
{
 if(x>=y && x>=z)
  return x;
 if(y>=x && y>=z)
  return y;
 if(z>=x && z>=y)
  return z;
}
```

Comment: Why the last `if(z>=x && z>=y) return z;` vs. just `return z;`?

Comment: Yes  ,that's a better idea but, Richard may get confused.